# How do I remove wall designations?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I ordered my dwarf to build a wall, but while he was carrying stone to it, I posted an alert making all dwarves drop what they were doing and run to the burrow point.

When the alert is turned off, no one resumes building the wall. I tried to remove the wall designation, but `d`->`n` does not work. `d`->`x` does not work either.

How do I remove a wall designation that hasn't been built yet? (also why do the dwarves not resume the task? Is it a bug?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `q` (Set building task/pref) button to look at the unbuilt section of wall. After doing so you can then either unsuspend construction (which is likely what happened) with the `s` key, or remove the building with the `x` key.